# Pidgin To Shoretel Call Manager IM

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin

Is anyone out there using Pidgin to connect with Shoretel's Instant Messaging?  Shoretel 9.2.  According to one of the docs I found on Shoretel's website, it should be connecting as a SIMPLE client but so far no dice.  It keeps getting an error resolving the server.  There's no proxy involved that I know of.  I was just wondering if anyone else had this particular configuration and if they'd made it work correctly.

Comment: Can you look at the configuration (specifically the server name) on a Call Manager Client? Have you tried entering the server IP address?

Comment: @Beaner, yes looked at the server name on the Call Manager Client and tried the server IP address.  No luck.  I just wondered if there were something else about this configuration that I needed to know.